# how to change wsgi server to localhost?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

world.

I am deploying a flask app and when I run the application and run.py, it runs on the `http:\\0.0.0.:9999` but I want to run it on my `localhost`. Where and how do I change this?

Attached is the terminal output
[run application terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpPdA.png)
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change it at the app.run line:

```
app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=9999)
```